# Android hidden app icon appear on home screen

Tags: android

As such I want to hide the icon from the launcher after the first run. icon is gone from launcher but its still appear on home screen.

I have seen similar applications - they can remove their own icons from the launcher app list.and their icons are not appear on home screen too.

i used following code to hide app icon. what i had made mistake ? why app icon appear on home screen ?

```
 PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this,
            com.aaa.xxx.dex.abc.class);

p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

note: icon gone from home screen samsung galaxy S4 mini ( 4.4.2 ), but it appear on home screen on samsung galaxy S3 ( 4.3.0 ) . any suggestions , help appreciated

thank you in advance ..

Comment: what is mean about it do crate any LAUNCHER activity in your manifest file

Comment: sorry but i cant understand what you explaining me . plealse be elaborate

Comment: why u want to hide app from from home screen

Comment: just think any most livewallpaer and widget not having home screen icon

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar my app is not livewallpaper app and not a widget. my app is just like a security app for user.

Comment: as far as I know you get a Icon for every Activity on your screen. Thus try to not have any activity in your manifest/app, only services etc.

Comment: can u post first activity on mainfest file

Comment: Use only Services on your app not use any activity on app

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar all activities and services are running very well. app is working perfectly i just got issue on 4.3.0 did you ever tried to hide app icon on 4.3.0 ?

Comment: Is your app a **virus**?

Comment: no @FrankN.Stein my app is just radio recorder and app lock.

Comment: And why do you want to use **stealth** techniques?!

Comment: Hava a look http://androidsnips.blogspot.in/2011/11/create-android-application-with-no.html?m=0

Comment: @FrankN.Stein do you have any answer regarding my question. I am here on stack overflow for answer of my question.

Comment: No. And I wouldn't share such a **dangerous** information.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void HideApp()
      {
        Intent localIntent = new Intent(cx.getApplicationContext(), yourClassName.class);
        cx.getApplicationContext().startService(localIntent);
        cx.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(newComponentName(cx,yourClssName.class), 2, 1);
}




public void Appear()
      {
        PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager(); 
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(context, yourClassName.class), 
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```